# Sending push notifications to change a tile from inside the App

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps

I have an App that is a "repository" of a lot of a citations and aphorisms; I would like to change the tile of my App for example every 5 seconds, by sending randomly some aphorism from my app!

Is it possible? Or I must pay some server service like Azure? In this case does exist something free?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the tile directly from your app:

```
var template = notifications.TileTemplateType.TileWideText01;                      
var xml = notifications.TileUpdateManager.getTemplateContent(template);
xml.getElementsByTagName("text")[0].appendChild(xml.createTextNode("My tile text"));
var myNotification = new notifications.TileNotification(xml);
notifications.TileUpdateManager.createTileUpdaterForApplication().update(myNotification);
```

There are [many different templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.notifications.tiletemplatetype%28v=win.10%29.aspx) you can choose from and you should probably update both a wide and a square tile at the same time because you don't know what the user has on his start screen. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh465439%28v=win.10%29.aspx)'s a bit more detail on how to do that.

I'm not sure you'll be able to get it to update every 5 seconds, though. You can only call the above code when your app is running or from a [BackgroundTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977045.aspx). If your app is on lock screen, you can use a [TimeTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj160504.aspx) and have it run at an interval of 15 minutes or less. If it's not then the only option is a [MaintenanceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh977060.aspx) with the same interval, which only runs when your device is plugged in.

To have the tile update more often and even when the device is not plugged in, you can [schedule tile notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh761473.aspx) in advance. When your app is running and from your BackgroundTask you can add up to 4096 tile changes for specific times and add new ones 
whenever your app or BackgroundTask is run again.

Answer (score 1):

The best way you can do this is to schedule your notifications from your background task. Your background task runs every 15 minutes (and not any sooner) so you will have to schedule them out at that point.

A coworker at MS had to do something similar as he needs updates every second (actually different person than the link below, but a very similar concept), and it was accomplished the same way. I have a tile helper class another coworker and I developed if you'd like it - shoot me an email adamt at Microsoft and I'll send it on over. I'll prob get around to doing a blog entry on it soon but until then : )

Some code that should get you most of the way there is:

[Tile update every minute](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff)

Linked to off of 
[Tile updates from Background Task](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-updates-from-2f6a854c/view/Discussions)